# how to pass path 'cd' portions to a shell function?

Tags: parameters, arguments

I'm trying something like this:

```
function projects(){
  cd;
  cd Documents/projects/$1;
}
```

but it doesn't work. What I'd like is to pass the name of the folder to add to the base path (so resulting in, say, cd Documents/projects/myfolder). Doing like so doesn't work:

```
projects myfolder
```

I can't figure out the right syntax. Searched the web but it should be right, but it's not :P I come form client side programming so I don't fully understand shell logics.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what exactly do you mean by that? Does it show an error message? Does it go somewhere entirely different?

Comment: Something like `cd: string not in pwd`

Comment: so it seaches the string in pwd instead of adding to the command

Answer (score 0):

A good idea would be to use the echo function on Documents/project then use it to echo you variable. Add them together and use the pipe(|) function to pipe them to cd

Comment: That doesn't make sense – `cd` accepts the path as command-line args, _not_ as stdin, and commands in a pipeline cannot affect the 'main' shell process.

Comment: ok grawity, thank you. So do you maybe have suggestions? :)